# c++ unordered_map iterator stop after erasing element within

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I am trying to make a function to calculate polynomial derivative with the polynomial storing in a hashmap, but i am not sure why the iterator stop while i am erasing element through the iteration. The code are as follow, the iterator will stop if `map.erase(i.first);` put in place

the hash key contains the exponent degree, the bucket contains the assoicated coefficient. The input polynomial is 3x^6 + 4x^4 + 6x^2 + 2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

unordered_map <int,int> derivative (unordered_map<int, int>& map) {
unordered_map <int, int> answer;
    map.erase(0);   // drop the constant in the polynomial

    for (auto i: map) {
        answer [i.first-1] = i.first * i.second;    //take the derivative
       // map.erase(i.first);     // erase the element after taking the derivative

    }
    return answer;
}

int main() {
    unordered_map <int,int> map = {{6,3},{4,4},{2,6},{0,2}};

    unordered_map<int,int> result = derivative(map);

    for (auto i: result)
        cout << i.second << "X^" << i.first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot erase current element from `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` while iterating with range loop, use iterators instead:

```
for( auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ) {
     if( condition ) map.erase( it++ );
     else ++it;
}
```

in your particular case it could be simplified to:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end; ) {
    answer[it->first-1] = it->first * it->second;    //take the derivative
    map.erase(it++);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I looked around but couldn't immediately find anything that prohibited this, particularly in light of the c++14 statement I found that makes iteration after erasure possible.

Comment: @MikelF In the range for `i` references the iterator.  When you delete it you now have a reference to a deleted iterator.  Using that is UB.

Comment: @MikelF as stated from this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for it implcitly uses iterator to current element, which is invalidated by `erase`. Changed wording for specific case to make it less confusing.

Comment: @RichardHodges as said in quotation when `erase()` starts side effects of postfix increment is done, which means `it` points to the next element. You need to read the same topic more carefully. Again that topic for `std::list` but `std::list` also invalidates iterator to erased element. If you disagree with answers in that topic or think that `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` is different open your own question or put your own answer.

Comment: @Slava You're right. I'm wrong. "When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline, and whether or not explicit function call syntax is used), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function." Will remove comments.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen `map.erase(it++)` used; everyone else does `it = map.erase(it)`. But it seems clear they are required to produce the same result. So, then, the return value of `.erase()` is purely for convenience/clearer code.

Comment: @underscore_d actually before C++11 `std::map::erase` return type was void, so this was the only way

Answer (score 2):

The following

```
for(auto i : map) {
    answer[i.first - 1] = i.first * i.second;    //take the derivative
    map.erase(i.first);     // erase the element after taking the derivative
}
```

is iterating over the elements. [If you erase one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6167117/1460794) of the elements with `map.erase(i.first);` while iterating then you get undefined behavior.

If you are using a c++14 compliant compiler you could explicitly use the iterator and update it with `erase`'s return value. That way elements [can be erased while iterating](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) through the container.

So you could do:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end; ) {
    answer[it->first-1] = it->first * it->second;    //take the derivative
    it = map.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  Looks right to me.