# List iterator is not incrementable

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm a bit rusty on c++ and am returning to it to get better. I searched a bit on StackOverflow already to no avail. The issue I am having is "list iterator not incrementable". Below is the section I believe to be the culprit, as this is the only location that I use an iterator with a modifier.

```
  if (!io_queue.empty()) {
        for (list<Process>::iterator it = io_queue.begin(); it != io_queue.end(); ++it) {
            if (it->isBurstDone()) {
                if (it->isComplete()) {
                    it->setExit(clock);
                    complete.push_back(*it);
                    it = io_queue.erase(it);
                }
                else {
                    ready_queue.push_back(*it);
                    it = io_queue.erase(it);
                }
            }
            else {
                it->decBurst();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider what happens if `it = io_queue.erase(it)` is called on the last valid element in the list?  What does the returned value of `it` represent and what happens if you then attempt to increment that value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ : List iterator not incrementable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167082/c-list-iterator-not-incrementable)

Comment: Thank you! Please disregard previous comment, added  a conditional for after the erase call to check if the new iterator is equivalent to element at the end of the list and this fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing `it` unconditionally on every loop iteration. But when `erase()` is called, it returns a new iterator to the next list element after the one being erased, and so if that results in `it` being set to the `end` iterator than incrementing `it` again is *undefined behavior*.

Simply move the `++it` from the `for` statement to the `else` block inside the loop.

Try this:

```cpp
if (!io_queue.empty()) {
    list<Process>::iterator it = io_queue.begin();
    do {
        if (it->isBurstDone()) {
            if (it->isComplete()) {
                it->setExit(clock);
                complete.push_back(*it);
            }
            else {
                ready_queue.push_back(*it);
            }
            it = io_queue.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            it->decBurst();
            ++it; // <— moved here
        }
    }
    while (it != io_queue.end());
}
```